# Playstore app review issue

Tags: android, publishing

I have published one app on the playstore 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.upperthrust.findmygarage

When I am checking out the number of ratings on the playstore, it shows the number 17. But, when I am checking the same through my playstore app publish dashboard it shows me the total ratings for my application are 51 from India and 1 from UAE. But still the total ratings are 17. I have never faced such issue before for any of my app. Can anyone help me out with this?

[image]

Comment: had a similar issue and contacted google. just wait for few days and it will be just fine.

Comment: @AksharPatel thank you